# Array-to-CSV-export function is facing an issue in WordPress-plugin

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, csv

I am using a simple array-to-CSV-export function in my plugin page for generating a report .

When I am running this code I am getting an error that it will export whole html content along with my expected array.

Here is my code:

```
function convert_to_csv($input_array, $output_file_name, $delimiter)
{
    clearstatcache();
    /** open raw memory as file, no need for temp files */
    $temp_memory = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
    /** loop through array  */



    foreach ($input_array as $line) {
        /** default php csv handler **/
        fputcsv($temp_memory, $line, $delimiter);
    }

    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($temp_memory); exit;
    /** rewrind the "file" with the csv lines **/
    fseek($temp_memory, 0);
    /** modify header to be downloadable csv file **/
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $output_file_name . '";');
    /** Send file to browser for download */
    fpassthru($temp_memory);
}

/** Array to convert to csv */

$array_to_csv = Array(
    Array(12566,
        'Enmanuel',
        'Corvo'
    ),
    Array(56544,
        'John',
        'Doe'
    ),
    Array(78550,
        'Mark',
        'Smith'
    )

);

clearstatcache();

convert_to_csv($array_to_csv, 'report.csv', ',');
```

Comment: I don't get an error when I run this code. I downloads the csv as expected.

Comment: when i am running this code in my plugin environment in WordPress then i am getting csv which shows all html code with the list

Comment: The code runs as expected for me and a csv file is downloaded.  Add info on the plug in and the Wordpress version to help us figure this out.

Comment: Do you have any kind of debugging enabled (`WP_DEBUG` set to true, or XDebug)? If so that could possibly contribute to extraneous HTML being rendered with your CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are doing well.

The way to fix your problem is.

We are adding an action on **init** because we don't want any HTML or other data from our website, and the very highest hook after wp_loaded is **init**
and adding **exit** to don't get other information from the website.

```php
<?php

add_action('init', function () {

    if (isset($_GET['generate_csv'])) {
        $array = array(
            array(12566, 'Enmanuel', 'Corvo'),
            array(56544, 'John', 'Doe'),
            array(78550, 'Mark', 'Smith'),
        );

        generate_csv($array);
        exit;
    }

});

function generate_csv($array)
{
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv");
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ($array as $row) {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Regards

Syed Ali Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that WP is carrying on with its normal operations after this function is called so you'll get the HTML template output after the CSV. Putting in an `exit` statement after `fpassthru` should do it, but you need to be careful that this doesn't mess up anything else that Wordpress does at the end of each page response. Drupal for example has a `drupal_exit()` function for just this purpose. I'm not familiar enough with WP to know for sure, but the documentation for the [wp_die() function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die) suggests that you can use PHP `exit` without too many problems

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to generate excel file with .xlsx extension

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alasql/0.3/alasql.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.7.12/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var insuranceArray = new Array(insuranceInfo);
    var bills = db.bills;

    //Create tabs in excel file
    var opts = [{sheetid:'Insurance Information',header:true},{sheetid:'bills Info',header:false}];

    alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("Data.xlsx",?) FROM ?', [opts, insuranceArray,bills]]);

    // Close the window once you save the file
    window.onfocus=function(){ 
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

This code works for me...

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the top of the export function.

```
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->hide_errors();
    @set_time_limit(0);
    if ( function_exists( 'apache_setenv' ) )
        @apache_setenv( 'no-gzip', 1 );
    @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);

    //@ob_clean();
    @ob_end_clean(); // to prevent issue that unidentified characters when opened in MS-Excel in some servers


        header( 'Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8' );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.csv' );
        header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
        header( 'Expires: 0' );

        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simplest way to generate csv without saving the file on the server

```
<?php
$array = Array(
    Array(
        12566,
        'Enmanuel',
        'Corvo'
    ),
    Array(
        56544,
        'John',
        'Doe'
    ),
    Array(
        78550,
        'Mark',
        'Smith'
    )
    
);
arr_to_csv($array);
function arr_to_csv($array)
{
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv");
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ($array as $row) {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }
}
```